# Why can't chktrust validate the signature of .msi files on CentOS 7?

Tags: security, centos, mono, windows-installer, digital-signature

I am currently working on a project to validate the digital signature of Windows PE files on a CentOS machine. I am able to validate the digital signature on Windows.

```
PS C:\Users\username> Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\package.msi' | Format-List


SignerCertificate      : [Subject]
                           CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

                         [Issuer]
                           CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2011, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

                         [Serial Number]
                           33000001519E8D8F4071A30E41000000000151

                         [Not Before]
                           5/3/2019 3:07:46 AM

                         [Not After]
                           5/3/2020 3:07:46 AM

                         [Thumbprint]
                           62009AAABDAE749FD47D19150958329BF6FF4B34

TimeStamperCertificate : [Subject]
                           CN=Microsoft Time-Stamp Service, OU=Thales TSS ESN:148C-C4B9-2066, OU=Microsoft Operations Puerto Rico, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

                         [Issuer]
                           CN=Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

                         [Serial Number]
                           330000010661B54499F8EAF2ED000000000106

                         [Not Before]
                           9/7/2019 2:11:19 AM

                         [Not After]
                           12/5/2020 2:11:19 AM

                         [Thumbprint]
                           63BDF81A1E55856AEE16F1BBE5B0BCCF5435F2F9

Status                 : Valid
StatusMessage          : Signature verified.
Path                   : C:\Users\username\Downloads\package.msi
SignatureType          : Authenticode
IsOSBinary             : False
```

However, for the same file `chktrust` returns the below response on CentOS.

```
[username@server ~]$ chktrust package.msi
Mono CheckTrust - version 6.8.0.123
Verify if an PE executable has a valid Authenticode(tm) signature
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

WARNING! package.msi is not timestamped!
ERROR! srvmgr.msi doesn't contain a digital signature!
```

Comment: `chktrust` seems to be a tool for verifying PE files (exe, dll, drv?). But MSI files have a different file format.

Comment: @Robert, How do I verify the digital signature of the MSI file on a Linux machine?

Comment: According it's description https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode can sign and verify PE+MSI.